# In Deadloch season 1, how did this character get this thing?

Tags: plot-explanation, deadloch

Note: this question is about the TV Series Deadloch, for which I haven't found a specific tag.

At the end of season 1 of Deadloch, we learn that the killer is

> Ray

Earlier in the season, during an outdoor screening

> multiple bodies comes to the surface. Those bodies appeared to have been frozen, and a car is pulled from the lake. The bodies where wearing seatbelt marks, indicating that they were in the car, and so the killer used the car to bring the bodies to the lake, and sunk the car to let the bodies thaw.

However, we then learn that the car belonged to

> William Carruthers. Not Ray. There is no indication that the 2 knew each other, and the storyline around the island suggests that Margaret killed William herself.

So, how did the killer obtained the car?

Also,

> did he freeze them in seating position? otherwise, how would he have been able to seat them in the car?